# converting while loop to a for each loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to rewrite this for loop into a for each loop.

```
 int k = 0;
  while(k < farmArray.length) {
     System.out.println(farmArray[k].getOwner());
     k++;
  }
```

This is what i've tried

```
int k = 0;
for(int Farm:farmArray)
{
  System.out.println(farmArray[k].getOwner());
 k += Farm;
}
```

can anyone point me in the right direction? thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the `k += Farm` bit. Just use the Farm variable -- but rename it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (Farm farm : farmArray) {
    System.out.println(farm.getOwner());
}
```

I think you were over-thinking it... :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove your index completely.

```
for(Farm farm : farmArray) {
    System.out.println(farm.getOwner());
}
```

Or you can keep track of you index

```
int k = 0;
for(Farm farm : farmArray) {
    System.out.println("Farm #" + k + " is owned by: " + farm.getOwner());
    k++;
}
```

But you should use a for loop for this

```
for(int k = 0; k < farmArray.length; k++) {
    System.out.println("Farm #" + k + " is owned by: " + farmArray[k].getOwner());
}
```

Comment: The first answer sufficed, thanks for the extended feedback though!

Comment: @aiuna No problem. These answers & questions are permanently archived, so if someone comes along and runs into a similar problem, they should know how to solve it!